# Green & Red light simulation

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a simple security system through the use of Java (eclipse) and there is going to be a control panel and when a user enters a correct pin the light will turn from red to green for 10 seconds (desired functionality). But I don't know how to make the lights.

Comment: Clarify what a "light" is. Are you referring to some kind of icon in Java's Swing library? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why don't you go, write some code, and give it a bash? We answer *specific programming problems*; rather than conceptual ones.

Comment: I have the access Panel programmed and all to accept pins and check these pins against pins in the database but it only says access granted if the check is successful but I want a green light to show if the check is successful (like traffic lights without the yellow haha)

Comment: Hi @user3073941, please show us what have you tried, there is many people who will willingly help you, but you have to show us some effort :)

Answer (score 2):

There shoould be a JLabel with 2 images (for red and green light). When pin is verified the label should be changed to show green image.

javax.swing.Timer should be started to invoke action in 10 secs. When the actionPerformed() of the timer is called just restore the red image for the label.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer mentioning `Timer`. BTW a simple `setBackground` would be enough and much simpler to implement.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik could be not enough if you want circles or some decorations etc. but for the simplest case background is enough

Comment: I think OP's current goal is to just have anything working :)

Answer (score 1):

Have an image that shows a lit red light, and an image that shows a lit green light. make your code display the red image until the pin is correct, then display your green image.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple JLabel, and add some round red image to it.
When the correct code is entered just swap to a green image and you're done.

But the others are right, just try it out a bit, and come back, when you have a specific problem handling this. Then we can see the code and base our answers on that.

EDIT: Ok, the others where faster :D